# Archivos estáticos 404 Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema con los estáticos de mi proyecto.
Cambie de computadora así que cree un clon del proyecto que tengo en mi repositorio, el problema es que ahora no carga mis archivos estáticos, cuando arranco el servidor en mi maquina local me muestra respuestas 404 al tratar de buscar los archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya cree el virtualenv, la active, instale el archivo requeriments.txt, ejecute el collectstatic y aplique las migraciones.

Esta es la configuración que tengo en settings para los archivos estaticos

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Aquí dejo el enlace al repositorio de mi proyecto
[Gestion_de_Recursos](https://github.com/ceragos/sisgerecu)

Comment: verifica tu   `STATICFILES_DIRS ` probablemente tenga la ruta de tu PC antigua alli

Answer (score 1):

En tu `ursls.py` requieres instanciar la ruta de los estáticos para que funcionen en local:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', login_required(index), name='index'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Si, es correcto. Esa es la configuración que tengo, pero el error que cometí fue dejar en settings el DEBUG en False

Answer (score 1):

La configuración que yo suelo usar en desarrollo es esta:

En el archivo **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Y en **urls.py** al final de todo

```
# importamos al configuración de django
from django.conf import settings

# comprobamos si el DEBUG esta establecido en True
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Con esto, una vez tengas el código en producción, tu servidor ya se encargará de usar los archivos usando al ruta que has establecido anteriormente en **settings.py**

Comment: Si, es correcto. Esa es la configuración que tengo, pero el error que cometí fue dejar en settings el DEBUG en False

Answer (score 0):

La configuración de las respuesta es la adecuada, sin embargo en mi archivo settings.py tenia el DEBUG en False, lo cual ocasionaba que no entrara en la ruta de los archivos estáticos. Cambie el valor de DEBUG por True y todo volvió a la normalidad.

Comment: Podes explicar mucho mejor esta respuesta? mira por favor [answeR]

Comment: Ademas tene en cuenta que se te dejaron respuestas, en las cuales nunca comentaste absolutamente nada. Estaban mal? no resolvian el problema?